# Проблема c логотипом и меню

Tags: wordpress

Выставил, чтобы лого отображалось по центру, а оно как было на месте, так и осталось, и так же меню.
Как поправить что бы то и то было по центру?

[image: Лого и меню]

А на других страницах, так 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    body{ background:#ffffff; margin:0; padding:0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#999;}
.center{ width:85%; margin:0 auto;}
img{max-width:100%}

/*Full width pages*/
body .no_sidebar{ width:100%;}


/*DIVIDERS*/
.optimizer_divider { width: 128px; height: 30px;margin: 0 auto; margin-top:30px;}
.optimizer_divider .div_left { width: 45px;height: 1px;background: #999; float: left;}
.optimizer_divider .div_right { width: 45px; float: left; height: 1px; background: #999;}
.optimizer_divider .div_middle {  float: left; margin: 10px; margin-top: -10px;line-height: 18px;}
.optimizer_divider .div_middle .fa-heart{font-size: 14px;}
.optimizer_divider .div_middle .fa-bolt{font-size: 18px;}
.optimizer_divider .div_middle .fa-stop{font-size: 14px;transform: rotate(45deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);position: relative;}
.optimizer_divider .div_middle i.fa-minus {width: 6px;position: relative;transform: rotate(117deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(117deg); -moz-transform: rotate(117deg);}
.optimizer_divider.title_underline .div_left { display: none;}
.optimizer_divider.title_underline .div_right { width: 45px; height: 3px; margin: 0 auto; float: none;display: block;}
.optimizer_divider.title_underline {  margin-top: 20px;}


/*HEADER*/
.header{width:100%; float:left;}
.header .center{ }
.header{-webkit-transition:all 0.4s ease-out;-moz-transition:all 0.4s ease-out;-ms-transition:all 0.4s ease-out;-o-transition:all 0.4s ease-out;transition:all 0.4s ease-out;}


/*LOGO*/
.logo{ float:left;max-width:100%;}
.logo h1, .logo h2{ float:left; font-size:36px; margin:12px 0; margin-bottom:0;}
.logo h1 a, .logo h2 a{ font-weight:bold;}
.logo img{ border:none; margin:10px 0;max-width:100%; height:auto;}

/*LOGO Alignment*/
.logo_right .logo { float: right;}
.logo_right #topmenu { float: left;}
.logo_center .logo { float: left; width:100%; text-align:center;}
.logo_center #topmenu { float: left; width:100%; text-align:center;}
.logo_center .logo h1, .logo_center .logo h2{ float:none;}
.logo_center #topmenu ul.menu>li{ padding:10px;}
/*DESCRIPTION*/
span.desc{ display:block; clear:both; font-size:14px; font-size:11px;opacity: 0.6; padding-bottom:10px;}


/*Mobile Menu*/
.head_inner{position: relative;width: 100%;float: left;}
#simple-menu{display: block;float: right;margin-top: 1.5%;color: #fff;font-size: 36px; position: absolute;right: 20px; top:15px;}
#simple-menu{ display:none;}
.pad_menutitle{padding: 5%;width: 90%;}
.pad_menutitle span{display: inline-block;float: right; cursor:pointer;}
/*Hide the mobile menu on desktop*/
#sidr-main{ display:none;}

#topmenu{text-align: right; margin-top:5px; display:block; vertical-align: middle;font-size: 0;}
#topmenu.has_bookmark .menu { display: inline-block;}
.has_trans_header.home #topmenu{vertical-align: initial;float: right;}
#topmenu ul{ margin:0; padding:0;}
#topmenu ul li{ list-style-type:none; display:inline-block;position: relative; margin:0; padding:0;}
#topmenu ul li a{display: block;padding: 20px; background:rgba(0,0,0,0); font-weight:bold;}


#topmenu .menu_hover > a{padding-bottom:12px;}
#topmenu ul li.current-menu-item a:hover, #topmenu .menu_hover.current-menu-item:hover > a {border: none;}
#topmenu ul li a, #topmenu ul li ul li{-webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;-moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;-ms-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;-o-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;transition:all 0.2s ease-out;}


#topmenu ul li ul{ display:none;  position: absolute;width: 200px;z-index: 9999999;margin-left:-50px;}
#topmenu ul li ul:not(.mega-sub-menu) {background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)!important;}
#topmenu ul li ul {  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.2s; -moz-animation-duration: 0.2s;animation-duration: 0.2s;}
#topmenu .menushow{ display:block;}
#topmenu ul li ul li{ margin:0; padding:0; width:100%; display:block; text-align:center;}
#topmenu ul li ul li a{ padding:12px 10%; width:80%; margin:0px; display:block; color:#fff;font-weight:normal;}

#topmenu ul li ul li ul{right: 100%; margin-top:-40px; float:none; margin-left:0px;}

#topmenu ul li span{ font-size:12px; opacity:0.5; padding-left:5px;}
#topmenu ul li ul li span{ display:none;}

#topmenu .zn_parent_menu:hover a{border:none!important;}

.has_trans_header.home #topmenu{ background-color:transparent!important;}

/*Menu Description*/
span.menu_desc {display: block;padding-top: 5px;}

/*Max mega menu Support*/
.mega-menu-item span.menu_arrow {display: none;}
#topmenu ul li.mega-menu-item ul li ul {background-color: transparent!important;}


#topmenu ul.menu>li:after, #frontsidebar .widget_nav_menu ul.menu>li:after {content: "";display: block;height: 2px;background-color: transparent;width: 0;margin: 0 auto;margin-top: -5px;-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;-moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;-ms-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;-o-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;transition:all 0.2s ease-out;}
#topmenu ul.menu>li:hover:after, #frontsidebar .widget_nav_menu ul.menu>li:hover:after{width: calc(100% - 40px);margin-top: 0;}

/*Mid Logo*/
.logo_middle{ opacity:0;}
.logo_middle .logo{ display:none;}
.logo_middle #topmenu {float: left;margin-top: 0;width: 100%;text-align: center;padding-bottom: 30px;}
.logo_middle #topmenu .logo{ display:inline-block; margin:0 40px; float:none;top: 15px;position: relative;}
.sidr-class-logo{ display:none;}


#topmenu li.menu_highlight{}
#topmenu li.menu_highlight_slim{}
#topmenu li.menu_highlight_slim, #topmenu li.menu_highlight{ padding-bottom:0; padding:8px 12px; border-radius:4px; border:2px solid transparent;-webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;-moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;-ms-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;-o-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;transition:all 0.2s ease-out;}
#topmenu li.menu_highlight_slim>a, #topmenu li.menu_highlight>a{ padding-bottom:30px;border: none;}
```

Comment: Выложите HTML и CSS.

Comment: Точно! Без кода ничего нельзя сказать. Чтобы его добавить, нажмите кнопку [edit].